# Listing contents of Array Printing at Incorrect Time (Opening Array from Marshall)

Tags: ruby, arrays, marshalling

Ruby Newbie here. I am working on a landlord application for class.

The idea is to be able to do certain functions that a landlord would be able to do to manage their properties. To accomplish this, I have a main menu method, which functions like this:

```
def main_menu
    puts "Please choose an option from the following menu:"
    puts "  1. List All Apartments"
    puts "  2. View Apartment Details"
    puts "  3. Add an Apartment"
    puts "  4. Add a Tenant"
    puts "  5. Evict a Tenant"
    puts "  6. Quit"

    input = gets.chomp
    case input
    when "1"
        list
    when "2"
        view(select_apt)
    when "3"
        add
    when "4"
        tenant(select_apt)
    when "5"
        evict(select_apt)
    when "6"
        File.open('listing.txt', 'w') {|file| file.truncate(0) }
        File.open('listing.txt', 'w')  {|file| file.write(Marshal.dump($array))}
    else
        puts "I'm sorry, that's not a valid option.\n\n"
        main_menu
    end
end
```

The purpose of the two lines in the quit option (6) is to be able to retrieve the array which contains each of the apartment objects. The global apartment array, $array, is created at the beginning of the program using:

```
$array = Marshal.load(File.binread('listing.txt'))
```

Originally, I was using a built in array to test, and everything was working the way I expected it to. Now, however, every function works with the exception of the List method:

```
def list
    puts "You have the following apartments:\n"
    $array.count.times do |i|
        if $array[i].renters.empty?
            print "#{$array[i].address}: is #{$array[i].sqft} square feet, has #{$array[i].num_beds} bedrooms and #{$array[i].num_baths} bathrooms. The monthly rent is $#{$array[i].monthly_rent}. \n\n"
        else
            print "#{($array[i].address)}: "
            print "#{view_tenants(i)}"
        end
    end

    main_menu
end
```

When I call the list method by selecting 1 at the main menu, it will only list the 1st apartment. Weirdly enough, when I attempt to exit, using "6", the program instead prints out info about the apartments, one by one. The output of the terminal is displayed here:

```
    Please choose an option from the following menu:
    1. List All Apartments
    2. View Apartment Details
    3. Add an Apartment
    4. Add a Tenant
    5. Evict a Tenant
    6. Quit
6
500Jane Street: Nicole is the sole tenant at this apartment.
Please choose an option from the following menu:
    1. List All Apartments
    2. View Apartment Details
    3. Add an Apartment
    4. Add a Tenant
    5. Evict a Tenant
    6. Quit
6
5001776, Floor 8: The renters living at the apartment are Jessica, and Jamie.

Please choose an option from the following menu:
    1. List All Apartments
    2. View Apartment Details
    3. Add an Apartment
    4. Add a Tenant
    5. Evict a Tenant
    6. Quit
6
500Please choose an option from the following menu:
    1. List All Apartments
    2. View Apartment Details
    3. Add an Apartment
    4. Add a Tenant
    5. Evict a Tenant
    6. Quit
6
Brandons-MacBook: Brandon $
```

Everything worked how I expected it to when I manually set an array equal to what I wanted it to be. Also, if I select the "View Apartment Details" option, it correctly lists out all of my current apartments(so that I can select one). It is only the "List All Apartments" option that gives me trouble. It is my first time using Marshall, so please let me know if I am doing something incorrectly. If necessary, I can provide more code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly whats causing the problem.

However, don't use globals in ruby, unless the variable represents the state of the program itself.

Read more here http://ruby.about.com/od/variables/a/Global-Variables.htm.

Try changing your global variable to an instance variable `@array`.
This variable is now seen throughout your class. Or even better a Constant.

If you have more than one instance of your class you could use a class variable `@@array`.
Now this variable can be seen by many instances of this class.
Note, ruby programmers try to avoid using class variables.

Also don't do `array.count.times`. Do `each` or `each_with_index`.